# Exchange Server Javascript Api

Tags: javascript, oauth, outlook, exchange-server, contacts

I'm building a web application which is a client side heavy application in which I'm implementing the contacts page. The contacts page will have options of showing contacts from different sources for exporting it into the current application. I've implemented Google Contacts, Yahoo Contacts, MS Live Contacts, etc. using OAuth. Now the next option is showing the contacts from exchange server in the application. I know that the new office 365 has a JavaScript api to pull contacts from newer office version which is already in progress. But I need a solution which works with older version too.

The requirement goes like this, User will have text boxes which are necessary to connect to an exchange server like email, password, server address, port, etc. and a button which need to send an ajax call to respective servers and fetch the necessary contact details after authenticating.

I've tried various method to get the details but I couldn't. I want to know is it really possible to connect an  exchange server from JavaScript to get contacts? If yes, Please suggest some method to view the details.

Comment: [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The new JavaScript for Office API can only be used with Office (web) Add-ins (formerly Apps for Office).  Otherwise you can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) to issue SOAP calls with JavaScript to do just about anything.

See: "[How to: Process contacts in batches by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn645424(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection3)"